# How to author Angular 4.3 app that gives me maximum performance yet supports IE11?

Tags: performance, angular, ecmascript-6

Here are my goals:

1. I would like to use ES2015 syntax for authoring my angular 4.3
   app.
2. I would like to target ES2015 for my angular app.
3. I would like to support chrome/firefox/edge with maximum performance (These
   browsers have good ES2015 support).
4. I would like to support IE11 (but don't need to be as performant). (As you know, IE11 does not have good ES2015 support).
5. I would like to use AOT (Ahead of Time) compilation to reduce the size of my app and for performance boost.
6. I do not want to penalize chrome/firefox/edge browsers because of polyfilling for IE11 or older browsers.

*How do I go about achieving my goals?* I am especially looking for knobs where and how to tweak my code and configuration to achieve my goals.

Note: I already read: https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: This is an opinion question more than a technical one, and that's not really what StackOverflow is for. If you have specific code you can't make work or need guidance on, then ask here. Any of the development paths you take with Angular4 will allow you to transpile to whatever target you want to configure, and as Angular is written in TypeScript, your best option is to code in TypeScript, and you'll find the most community support for that as well. There are polyfill solutions that load dynamically based on your browser, so you don't need to penalize any browser to support others.

Comment: Don't target ES2015. Don't use features that cannot be polyfilled in ES5 and IE11 in particular. As simple as that. Nobody can read the manual for you to tell what these features are in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend using the Angular CLI: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

It defaults to TypeScript (not ES 2015) which is a better choice anyway.

It provides appropriate polyfills for IE 11.

It automatically handles AOT.

Check it out.

Comment: TypeScript and ES 2015 are not mutually exclusive. TS is a superset of ES and can be compiled to several ES editions.

Comment: Yes of course. But I thought the OP was referring to coding directly in ES 2015 (without TypeScript).

Comment: I guess the answer could explicitly state that TS needs to be configured with 'es5' target as a common denominator.